# The rain is "lifting"

Tags: american-english, word-usage, colloquialisms, figures-of-speech, dialects

How can the rain "lift"?

I mean, I can pretty well figure out that the fog or mist or smog, etc. "lifts", i.e. disappears or disperses by or as if by rising, but "the rain lifting" sounds like it's swallowing itself back up into the clouds, sort of in the same way as the rain sequence from a movie that would be playing backward. Or is it a natural meteorological process involving vapor that is described here?

In addition, what other weather events aside from the rain, fog, smog, etc.,  "lift", that is, go away until none is left?

For example, does a snowfall, thunderstorm, hurricane, or hailstorm "lift"?

> lift
>
> 2. *v. intr.*
>
> a. To disappear or disperse by or as if by rising: *By afternoon the smog had lifted*.
>
> b. To stop temporarily: *The rain lifted by morning*. [American Heritage® Dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/lift)

Comment: The rain was oppressing us.  That oppression is lifting.

Comment: I think it is kind of a metonymy. When you say "rain lifted", "rain"
 refers to the "rain cloud".

Comment: I suspect that hurricanes have lifted many things. ;)

Comment: In addition to the other comments/answers, rain can lift in the sense that it stops reaching the ground.  That is, it falls as rain from a cloud but evaporates before reaching the ground.  This is called ***virga*** and is quite common.  (Although virga almost always occurs before any rain, rather than after.)

Comment: Something similar to the rain lifting would be the rain *letting up.*  It's not really going back up, it's just settling...down.  You might also ask someone to *let up* if they are berating them excessively.  The berating person won't be going anywhere, they'll just be getting the message to ease up, lighten up, cool down, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This meaning of 'lift', the range of meaning that includes "a rain lifting", is part of a much larger montage or (if only we knew enough to see the connectedness of the whole) tapestry of meaning that might be said to explain any one use. The range of meaning that includes rain lifting also includes all atmospheric phenomena that increase visibility as they cease: darkness itself lifts, as does snow, hail, fog, smog, etc. So also are curtains and drapes 'lifted' when in fact they may only be moved aside.

The continued application of 'lift' to describe the cessation of atmospheric phenomena that increase visibility as they decrease testifies to the primacy of *appearance* as a driver of meaning. So, we say "the rain lifted" for much the same reason the 'solstice' (from "*sōl* sun ... + participial stem of *sistĕre* to stand still", *OED Online*) is called the solstice: on that day, to an observer from the limited perspective of earth, the sun appears to stand still. The rain that 'lifts' does appear to vanish into the gradually revealed sky...and an Old Norse word meaning 'sky' ("Old Norse *lopt* air, sky = lift *n.*<sup>1</sup>" op. cit.) is a source of the first attested uses of 'lift' in English. In those uses the original meaning of 'lift', that is, 'the air, atmosphere, sky', a sense now mostly obsolete, is preserved:

> **lift**, *n.*<sup>1</sup>
>   ....
>   *Obs.* exc. *Sc.* and *poet.*
>   The sky, upper regions; †in early use also, the air, atmosphere. Also pl., the (seven) heavens.
>   OE   *Beowulf* 2832   Nalles æfter lyfte lacende hwearf.
>   c1000   *Sax. Leechd.* II. 146   Romane him..worhton eorþ hus for þære lyfte wylme & æternesse.
>   OE   *Maxims* II 39   Fugel uppe sceal lacan on lyfte.
>   c1175   *Lamb. Hom.* 79   Of þe uisces iþe wetere and fuȝeles iþe lufte.

["lift, n.1". OED Online. December 2015. Oxford University Press. http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/108135 (accessed January 03, 2016).]

---

The foregoing explanation, while complete in itself, discounts the *virga* effect by relegating it to a secondary role in the continued use of 'lift' to describe the lifting of rain. This is because, while the *virga* effect applies to rain, it does not apply equally to darkness lifting, or the lifting of hail, sleet, or other atmospheric phenomena. The *virga* effect does, however, apply uniquely to rain, and may partly explain the continued use of 'lift' to describe the cessation of rain.

Simply, the *virga* effect, and 'virga' itself, names this phenomenon:

> **virga**, *n.*
>   ....
>   2. *Meteorol.* Streaks of precipitation that appear to be attached to the undersurface of a cloud and usually evaporate before reaching the ground.

Raindrops, as it happens, start large in the clouds but, due to evaporation, diminish as they fall, and especially so in dry air. The raindrops also disperse as they fall, and so many rain showers appear lighter at the lower levels than the upper levels when viewed from a distance. In very dry air, it is common to be able to see in the distance a rain shower that vanishes altogether before reaching the ground. As such a shower gradually shrinks and ceases, then, the rain *appears* to lift into the cloud that produced it, disappearing from the bottom up, rather than the top down.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think the OED citations apply.  I think lift in this case is probably more to do with rain's intensity described as "heavy" and "light" there for "the rain is lifting" means becoming less severe.  The support for the above references is that, in my opinion rarely used, when the rain is completely gone one can say "the rain has lifted."

Answer (score 3):

According to the OED *to lift* referring to rain means *to cease temporarily* in AmE probably by analogy with other weather phenomena (fog, etc.)

***To lift:***

> - Of clouds, fog, etc.: To rise and disperse. ***Also (U.S.) of rain: To cease temporarily.***

Usage examples:

> - ***1834*** M. Scott Cruise Midge vi. (1842) 102 The clouds..lifted from the eastern horizon majestically slow.
> - ***1858*** Froude Hist. Eng. III. 349 One morning when the darkness lifted, sixty strange sail were found at anchor in the Downs.
> - ***1870*** E. Peacock Ralf Skirl. II. 178 The thick fog had lifted. 1901
> - ***fig. 1897*** M. Kingsley W. Africa 232 My..head-ache..soon lifted. -

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Can other meteorological phenomena "lift", i.e. go away until none is left, as quoted by haha below?

Comment: @Elian -      I can see it is mainly used referring to mist, fog,  clouds, what other meteorological phenomena are you thinking about?

Comment: Things like snowfalls, thunderstorms, hurricanes, and hailstorms. Can you say, for example, that the snow "lifted/is lifting"? If so, what would "lift" suggest in terms of natural phenomenon?

Comment: @Elian -          Usage appears to be limited to mist/fog/clouds and rain (probably because like the other phenomena it is a common one). Those you cite (hailstorms etc.) are less common and more violent phenomena. ***To lift:*** of mist/clouds
[intransitive] to rise and disappear
(synonym disperse) 
The fog began to lift.
(figurative) Gradually my depression started to lift. http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/american_english/lift_1

Answer (score 2):

According to the definition of **lift** in [Cambridge Dictionary](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/lift?q=Lift) it actually makes sense.

> **Lift**
>
> To go away until none is left.

Comment: A fog going away until none is left has kind of an eerie connotation to it. :-)